# Cannot find module 'puppeteer-core/internal/common/Device.js'

Tags: puppeteer

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. I installed pupeteer using npm i puppeteer (using WSL ubuntu)
2. When I try to load pupeteer in a simple test (`import puppeteer from "puppeteer";`) I get the error `Cannot find module 'puppeteer-core/internal/common/Device.js' from 'node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/puppeteer.js'`

Any ideas what the issue is?

Pupeteer version: 19.0.0
Node.js version; 16.17.0
npm version: 8.19.2

Script example:

```
import puppeteer from "puppeteer";

describe("App.js", () => {
  let browser;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  });

  afterAll(() => browser.close());
});
```

log output:

> FAIL  src/App.e2e.test.js   ● Test suite failed to run
>
> ```
> Cannot find module 'puppeteer-core/internal/common/Device.js' from 'node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/puppeteer.js'
>
> Require stack:
>   node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/puppeteer.js
>   src/App.e2e.test.js
>
> > 1 | import puppeteer from "puppeteer";
>     | ^
>   2 |
>   3 | describe("App.js", () => {
>   4 |   let browser;
>
>   at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:324:11)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/puppeteer/src/puppeteer.ts:18:1)
>   at Object.<anonymous> (src/App.e2e.test.js:1:1)
>   at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
>   at runJest (node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:404:19)
> ```
>
> Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total

Comment: do you use device emulation (`puppeteer.devices`) anywhere in the test? in general your script example would be useful to reproduce the issue. there were breaking changes in v19 that may affect your tests.

Comment: @theDavidBarton I added a script example. It fails even if I do almost nothing. I suspect WSL is the deal breaker

Comment: I see. I cannot test it with WSL at the moment but I think it is a bug on puppeteer's side and related to their latest changes (started with 18.2.0 when they split puppeteer from puppeteer-core). I suggest raising a ticket for them on Github, such reported bugs are fixed quickly, and it may affect more Linux distros. in the meantime, I'd try it with `npm i puppeteer@18.1.0` if it solves the issue (it was released only 10 days ago, you will have a kinda up-to-date package)

Comment: update: I just did a quick search and it seems puppeteer has never run under WSL out of the box. the error message may changed over time so it was not the same as yours above but I think you should follow the suggestions at the bottom of this thread: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/1837 (so my suggestion about downgrading puppeteer won't be a solution for sure)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot. I am able to run the test if I downgrade to 18.1.0, add chrome.exe from Windows to $PATH and add 'chrome.exe' as well as '--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox' to the puppeteer.launch arguments. However with the newest puppeteer version I get the error "Cannot find module 'puppeteer-core/internal/common/DeviceDescriptors.js'"

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue on MacOS regarding a missing puppeteer-core/internal module except the error message I received was:

```
Cannot find module 'puppeteer-core/internal/puppeteer-core.js' from 'puppeteer.js'

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:169:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/puppeteer.js:33:14)
```

I was able to fix it by just rolling back versions of both puppeteer and jest.

```
npm install jest@22.1.4
npm install puppeteer@18.1.0
```

Answer (score 5):

I was able to fix it with:

> npm i puppeteer@18.1.0

Then adding chrome.exe from Windows to my $PATH

And changing the test to

```
browser = await puppeteer.launch({ 
      executablePath: 'chrome.exe', 
      headless: true,
      args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox']
    });
```